# Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2015

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В преддверии выборов в модераторы сообщества мы планируем провести сессию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами. Такая сессия дает возможность участникам сообщества задать вопрос кандидатам. Участие полностью добровольное.

План таков.

- Во время фазы номинации данная публикация будет доступна для добавления возможных вопросов от участников сообщества. Добавьте ответ к этой публикации содержащий любой вопрос, который вы хотите задать кандидату. Пожалуйста, добавляйте *один вопрос в одном ответе*.
- Команда развития сообществ предоставит небольшой набор базовых вопросов. Первые два из них обязательно войдут в список вопросов кандидатам, Остальные попадут в него только в том случае, если сообщество не предложит достаточно альтернативных вопросов.
- Сессия вопросов – это прекрасная возможность понять, каким образом кандидат смотрит на специфичные в настоящий момент проблемы именно нашего сообщества.
- По завершении стадии номинации команда развития сообществ выберет **до 8 вопросов от участников сообщества, набравших наибольшее количество голосов**. Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к двум вышеупомянутым обязательным вопросам. Команда развития сообществ оставляет за собой право вносить правки в вопросы так, чтобы они соответствовали выборам. В любом случае, если возникнут какие-либо замечания по содержанию вопросов, мы постараемся описать их в виде комментариев, дав автору возможность внести изменения.
- Как только сообщество определится с вопросами, будет создан новый вопрос, предназначенный для сбора ответов от кандидатов.
- Это не единственная возможность запросить информацию у кандидатов. Вы, как участник сообщества, например, можете задать любой другой вопрос кандидатам или уточнить один из существующих в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Если у вас есть вопросы о процессе или вам есть чем его дополнить, пожалуйста, оставьте *комментарий* к этому вопросу.

#### Итоги

Целью данной публикации было собрать список вопросов для кандидатов в модераторы 2015. Итоговый список доступен в публикации «[Выборы модераторов сообщества 2015: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2147/)».

Comment: А когда планируются выборы?

Comment: @Suvitruf по прошествию 10 дней с момента начала этапа номинации.

Comment: Может, разблокируем? Выборы кончились.

Comment: Подскажите, какою видите альтерантиву блокировке?

Answer (score 12):

Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Comment: Этот вопрос и так уже задан почти каждому кандидату в комментариях. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin так пусть каждый и ответит, отдельным пунктом =) Вообще читать комментарии становиться почти невозможно, их очень много и они все очень большие.

Comment: @Vartlok в комментариях  в основном кандидаты между собой бодаются. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ещё один забавный нюанс в том, что этот вопрос практически повторяет стандартный вопрос из ответа Николаса. :)

Answer (score 9):

В этом ответе вы можете найти набор базовых вопросов, призванных раскрыть как можно более общую информацию о кандидате. Как написано в инструкциях выше, первые два вопроса гарантированно появятся в итоговой сессии вопросов и ответов. Остальные только в том случае, если сообщество опубликует недостаточно вопросов. Если вы считаете, что какой-то вопрос из списка, помимо двух верхних, должен войти в итоговую сессию, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в виде отдельного ответа.

- Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?
- Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

- Что, по вашему мнению, делает модератор?
- «Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?
- Каким образом статус модератора сделает ваши действия более эффективными в сравнении с ситуацией, когда вы просто наберете 10 или 20 тысяч баллов репутации?

Answer (score 9):

- Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний
  день?
- Как они мешают развитию сообщества?
- Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

Answer (score 9):

Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

Answer (score 8):

Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь?

С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Answer (score 8):

Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать? Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.

Comment: В качестве фотопа. А что на Мете какие-то решения принимаются? Где-то можно их список увидеть?

Comment: @Cerbo: Практически все решения принимаются на Мете. Вы спалились :)

Comment: @Cerbo Каждый раз, когда на Мете возникает [meta-tag:обсуждение] какой-то проблемы, народ решает, что делать. Остальные за эти решения голосуют (или за вопрос, или за ответы — как представлено). Для не слишком радикальных изменений решение после этого можно считать принятым. В сложных случаях надо отдельно разбираться, но в целом большинство вопросов всё равно решается преимущественно на Мете.

Comment: Вообще я думал что Мета это просто Q&A по самому руСО плюс я обращал внимание что Мета тяготеет к форуму. Но я не предпологал что здесь принимаются решения которые к чему-то обязывают. По-честному это должно быть в правилах явно написано.

Comment: @Cerbo, формально это есть [в правилах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): *В отличие от «обычных сайтов» сети Stack Exchange, Мета позволяет сообществу обсуждать, аргументировано спорить, предлагать изменения жизни самого сообщества и работы программного обеспечения. Для сообщений, обозначенных как «[meta-tag:предложение]», голосование обозначает согласие (одобрение) или несогласие с предлагаемым изменением, а не качество или пользу самого сообщения.*

Comment: @Nofate Спасибо, что тыкнули меня носом, не замечал этой фразы.

Answer (score 8):

Просматривая историю своих проверок, вы обнаруживаете, что ваше мнение очень часто расходится с мнением большинства. Ваши действия?

Comment: Сменю ник на `д'Артаньян` =)))

Comment: И вариант для самого @Discord'а: Просматривая [распределение голосов](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/411661/525971/), вы  обнаруживаете, что у вас самый низкий показатель голосов за - всего 38%, тогда как у всех остальных кандидатов более 50%. Ваши действия?

Comment: @Qwertiy Что ж вы не как ответ этот вопрос запостили? Я бы плюсанул. :) Впрочем, он всё равно не всплывёт, поэтому в качестве исключения отвечу здесь. Никаких действий, всё правильно. Во-первых, мне очень далеко до [рекордсменов](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/300464/most-evil-users). Во-вторых, я очень много времени провожу в чистке старого хлама, а также в очередях проверок. Я бы наоборот поставил под сомнение вашу способность объективно оценивать качество вопросов, учитывая, что минусы вы практически не ставите, хотя число проверок у вас соразмеримо с моим. Ваш ход. :)

Comment: Но ведь кроме вариантов проголосовать за и проголосовать против есть вариант просто пройти мимо. Как я в большинстве случаев и поступаю с посредственными вопросами. Вопросы с нулевым рейтингом ведь тоже собираются Духом, если там достойных ответов нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. Незакрытые оффтопичные вопросы стимулируют написание ответов на оффтопичные вопросы, а потому и написание оных. Это вред наполнению сайта. 2. Рейтинг вопросов используется при поиске и фильтрации. Если оффтопичные и некачественные вопросы не заминусованы, пользователю сложнее оценить полезность, и он тратит больше времени на поиск. Это тоже вред сайту. / В целом, честные оценки и голоса за открытие и закрытие нужны для упрощения поиска нужной информации и стимуляции написания качественных вопросов и ответов.

Comment: @Discord, я не говорил про оффтопик (который, кстати, надо закрывать, а не минусовать), я говорил про обычные средненькие вопросы, которых тут довольно много. Они вполне тематические, недостаточно плохие, чтобы поставить минус, но и не представляющие ничего интересного, чтобы поставить плюс. Я не знаю, чему конкретно ты ставишь минусы (тем более, перебором старых вопросов я не занимаюсь - на эту тему у меня тоже другое мнение), но на основе статистики возникает подозрение, что примерно половину твоих минусов можно было просто не ставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Подавляющее большинство моих минусов на том мусоре, который я чищу. Минусы на новые посты я ставлю, только если их нельзя спасти. Ставил бы чаще, если бы система удосуживалась уведомлять об исправлениях в заминусованных мной постах. А сейчас получается, что, поставив минус, я с большой вероятностью никогда его не исправлю. Поэтому от минусов на новых постах "средней паршивости" больше вреда, чем пользы, поэтому я их обычно не оцениваю никак.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 8):

Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):

> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском

Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Answer (score 8):

Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Answer (score 8):

Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Comment: Всё просто - затеять `драму` в чате и ждать пока на оппонетна применится закон Годвина)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: У нас, кажется, более актуально `нытьё` :)

Comment: А, точно) Просто ныть в последнее время стало сложнее - с части моих постов эту метку выпиливают( Приходится даже специально в тело поста добавлять обоснование её наличия) А так да - представил себе возможность писать на мете с ромбом и ныть... Круто, надо таки самовыдвинуться. и упирать на то, что буду самым ноющим модером)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Метку из поста выпилить можно, а вот _нытьё_ — сложнее.

Answer (score 7):

На текущий момент есть проблема: неопытные пользователи, столкнувшись с негативным отношением к своему вопросу, не пытаются улучшить вопрос, а просто забрасывают его и уходят. Какие вы видите пути решения этой проблемы? (Краткосрочные? Долгосрочные?)

Answer (score 5):

Как вы предлагаете решать проблему участников, которые «втихую» закрывают/открывают вопросы, не читая посты на Мете и не обсуждая модерацию в чате?

Answer (score 5):

Что вы предлагаете делать с новичками, которые задают вопросы по учебным заданиям? Есть ли стратегия лучше, чем просто закрывать вопросы?

Comment: подобные вопросы вызывают (гипотетическое) желание взять и задать студентам в качестве учебного задания серию самых популярных и полезных вопросов :) Вы предлагаете модераторам игнорировать [текущий консенсус](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044) и придумывать свои правила? Мне кажется эта тема никогда не будет закрыта и поэтому модераторы не должны навязывать своё мнение. [Задача модераторов обрабатывать исключения из правил, а не создавать свои единолично](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: @jfs: «Я придерживаюсь текущего консенсуса» + ссылка — тоже валидный ответ.

Comment: @jfs Вопрос не в том что модератор должен решить эту проблему, а в том какова его позиция.

Comment: @Cerbo: если ответ не должен влиять на конкретные действия человека как модератора, то зачем спрашивать? Почему бы не спросить о позиции касательно отмены смертной казни, легализации потребления наркотиков,  о security theater, etc? Подобные вопросы указывают в каком общем направлении человек сайт будет толкать, но мы их не задаём так как они не должны  конкретные действия менять.

Comment: @jfs Если вы имеете в виду мета-вопрос про работу за автора по вашей ссылке выше, то это не правило потому, что его нет в справке. Следовательно вопрос корректен и важно знать мнение будущего модератора на эту тему.

Comment: @jfs: Реальная проблема в том, что в последнее время (да и всегда в окрестности сессии) задаётся довольно много некачественных вопросов. Среди них выделяются (заслуживающие закрытия по одной из общепринятых причин) вопросы по д/з. Мой вопрос состоит в том, можно ли кроме обычного полагающегося в этом случае закрытия сделать что-нибудь ещё, более эффективное/полезное? Или кандидат предлагает ограничиться формальным критерием.

Comment: Как я уже сказал выше *"эта тема никогда не будет закрыта"* -- можно разные решения обсуждать, пробовать и посмотреть что работать будет -- но выборы модераторов тут то при чём?

Comment: @jfs: Меня интересует отношение кандидата в модераторы к этой проблеме. Исходя из голосов, ещё 10 человек этот вопрос интересует, а трёх, наоборот, не интересует.

Answer (score 5):

Как модератор, вы больше не сможете выносить закрытие вопроса на рассмотрение другими участниками. Вы сможете или сразу закрыть, или молча пройти мимо. Считаете ли вы, что решение о закрытии вопросов должно приниматься в первую очередь сообществом, и модератор должен лишь направлять и поддерживать его? Или вы будете просто закрывать вопросы в одиночку?

Answer (score 5):

если бы вступление в должность модератора требовало принесения [присяги](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0), в чём, по-вашему, должен был бы поклясться в ней будущий модератор?

Answer (score 4):

Что, по вашему, должно быть не первом месте?

1. Дисциплина. Следует строго "чистить" неадекватные материалы и таким образом добиваться их высокого качества. На качественные материалы придут качественные пользователи, а других нам не надо.
2. Либо количество пользоватлей. Стараясь привлечь больше пользователей, проявлять большую лояльность к новичкам, позвалять им публиковать (не закрывать/удалять) неадекватные материалы. Постепенно учить новичков, превращая их в качественных пользователей публикующих качественные материалы.

Answer (score 2):

- Каково ваше отношение к чату?
- Будете ли вы там появляться?
- Сколько времени собираетесь уделять чату?
- Собираетесь ли вы его модерировать?
- Если да, то какие у вас планы по этому поводу?

Comment: плюсанул, комментарии удаляю, чтобы не подсказывать кандидатам. ))

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютное большинство пользователей StackOverflow не имеют учетной записи. Они просто заходят на сайт и ищут ответы на свой вопрос, но не задают собственных и не голосуют за вопросы и ответы.

Как вы считаете, как можно привлечь больше посетителей к активному участию?

Answer (score 1):

Каких пользователей вы бы хотели видеть в модераторах, а каких кандидатов нет? Почему?

PS: Обращаю внимание на пользователей/кандидатов в разных частях вопроса.

Comment: Стрёмный вопрос, ведущий к спорам.

Comment: @LEQADA, к каким спорам? Это вроде вопросы для кандидатов лично, а не для дебатов между кандидатами? Если кто-то скажет на один из ответов "не-не, ты не прав, я [твоё мнение] лучше знаю" - то что-то тут не то ;)

Answer (score 0):

Какие возможности модератора вы считаете наиболее полезными для себя? Чем вы будете пользоваться наиболее часто и для решения каких задач?

Какими возможностями вы будете пользоваться меньше всего?

Comment: Интересный вопрос если учесть что открытой информации об инструментах, доступных только модераторам, практически нет.

Comment: @PashaPash: есть достаточно неплохо документированные возможности, например единоличные операции с сообщениями, спецметки Меты и т.п. Если человек интересуется вакансией модератора, он должен уже знать хоть о чем-то.

Comment: Да, должен. Но вопросы и ответы на них - прежде всего для голосующих, а не для кандидатов. Я не думаю что ответ "буду прежде всего просматривать синюю очередь" будет понятен всем  голосующим :)

Comment: @PashaPash: удалил упоминание инструментов. Я хочу акцентировать внимание именно на возможностях. Вдруг кто-то больше всего хочет банить )

Answer (score 0):

**2**. Если человек нагрубил вам на просторах нашего сообщества, но под раздел бана не попадает , как вы будите действовать в этой ситуации?

**Примечание:** Ответ принимается если будет содержать не менее 250 символов.

Comment: Большой серой массе нужна пища , которая ей по зубам, например, такая как в телевизоре.

Answer (score 0):

Cитуация: был конкурс [о MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445), новичок дал ответ именно [о MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972), но его не заметили, а выиграл ответ, в котором была неточность. ее исправили после [комментария новичка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-mvp-winforms/413461#comment541993_413461) и это тоже не заметили. Как в такой ситуации вы поступите?

Answer (score -1):

Какими вы видите цели и направления развития сообщества на будущий 2016 год?

Answer (score -2):

Что такое модерирование? В каком модерировании нуждается руСО?

Answer (score -2):

Как думаете, что можно сделать вопросами, которые имеют *правильный ответ*. Автор в комментариях сказал *Спасибо* и что *Это помогло*. Но *не поставил галочку (правильный ответ)* и давно не появляется в системе.

*Что нужно делать такими ответами?* Нужно ли модератору сделать этот Ответ Правильним за того пользователья?

Или скажите свое мнение.

[Обсуждение из мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/168/182317)

Comment: Модератор не может это сделать чисто физически.

Comment: ну да, он не сможет. Возможно дадут идею, добавления функции Ставить галочку Коллективно. Главное, это мышление кандидата.

Comment: Это уже обсуждалось 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18315/310448

Comment: Прочитайте комментарии по своей ссылке.

Comment: @LEQADA в обоих ссылка мнения разные. Думаю нужно опиратся на мета на русском

Comment: Просто внимательно прочитайте комментарии по своей ссылке.

Comment: @LEQADA да Вы правы. Но может этот вопрос поможет в выборе кандидата, хотья есть ответ

Comment: @LEQADA это гипотетический вопрос - возможно, кто-то при наличии фичи пользовался бы ей, а кто-то - нет. Если бы ответ был очевидным то не возникало бы тем "что делать если принятый ответ - плохой"

Comment: @PashaPash, эти вопросы возникают только из-за того, что возможности движка нигде в явном виде не задокументированы. Их нужно искать по кускам по всему SE.

Comment: @LEQADA возможности модератора вообще не документированы. И я не уверен, должна ли по ним быть публичная документация.

Answer (score -4):

Как поступать с вопросами, на которые даны ответы и есть явно правильный, но автор не выбрал правильный?

Автор например не зарегистрирован или больше не посещает SO, а выбор правильного ответа поможет следующим пользователям и прибавит рейтинг ответчику.

Comment: В таком случае нужно читать эти вопросы: [Что делать: ответ не принят, пользователя нет?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1299) [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/167)

Answer (score -13):

Чего Вы достигли в жизни на данный момент? Чего ещё ждёте от жизни?

Answer (score -16):

Расскажите о своём отношении к самой популярной теме этого сайта - [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
Считаете ли Вы эту технологию перспективной?

Comment: Надо было сформулировать вопрос так: что лучше, PHP или Python?

Comment: Или linux или bsd?