# Показывать участнику как он голосовал в заблокированных темах

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено, дизайн, блокировка

Предлагаю показывать выбранную стрелку голосования на страницах с исторической блокировкой. А то иногда интересно узнать, за что ты голосовал.

Пример: [Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2015](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2028/178988)

На странице достаточно данных, чтобы это сделать:

```css
.ice-ice-baby .votecell .vote-up-on,
.ice-ice-baby .votecell .vote-down-on {
  display: block;
  opacity: .1;
}
```

Comment: Конечно, надо. Даже не представлял, что там иное отображение.

Comment: `.ice-ice-baby` это за блокировку отвечает? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ага, но висит на вопросе и на каждом ответе :)