# Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2017

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В преддверии выборов в модераторы сообщества, которые начнутся ровно через неделю, 9 октября 2017 года, мы планируем провести сессию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами. Такая сессия дает возможность участникам сообщества задать вопрос кандидатам. Участие полностью добровольное.

План таков.

- Во время фазы номинации данная публикация будет доступна для добавления возможных вопросов от участников сообщества. Добавьте ответ к этой публикации содержащий любой вопрос, который вы хотите задать кандидату. Пожалуйста, добавляйте *один вопрос в одном ответе*.
- Команда развития сообществ предоставит небольшой набор базовых вопросов. Первые два из них обязательно войдут в список вопросов кандидатам, Остальные попадут в него только в том случае, если сообщество не предложит достаточно альтернативных вопросов.
- Сессия вопросов и ответов — это прекрасная возможность понять, как кандидат смотрит на специфичные в настоящий момент проблемы нашего сообщества.
- По завершении стадии номинации команда развития сообществ выберет **до 8 вопросов от участников сообщества, набравших наибольшее количество голосов**. Эти вопросы будут использоваться в дополнение к двум вышеупомянутым обязательным вопросам. Команда развития сообществ оставляет за собой право вносить правки в вопросы так, чтобы они соответствовали выборам. В любом случае, если возникнут какие-либо замечания по содержанию вопросов, мы постараемся описать их в виде комментариев, дав автору возможность внести изменения.
- Как только сообщество определится с вопросами, будет создан новый вопрос, предназначенный для сбора ответов от кандидатов.
- Это не единственная возможность запросить информацию у кандидатов. Вы, как участник сообщества, например, можете задать любой другой вопрос кандидатам или уточнить один из существующих в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Если у вас есть вопросы о процессе или вам есть чем его дополнить, пожалуйста, оставьте **комментарий к этому вопросу**.

---

Вот вопросы, предложенные на прошлые выборы: [Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2015](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2028/181472)

Comment: Ну, наконец-то...

Comment: А давайте вместо выборов, просто назначим нужных людей? ;-)

Comment: @Grundy не хватает фотографии Ванги.

Comment: @alexolut, и фото Grundy с подписью: "Их разыскивает модерка".

Comment: [Вопросы с выборов-2015](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2028/208074) будут добавляться в список?

Comment: @Arhad Сами собой — нет, только если они будут добавлены в этот вопрос ответами.

Comment: @Arhad только если не хватит новых вопросов. Но их хватит.

Comment: А как быстро, обычно, модераторы на тревоги реагируют? Я уж пол часа как тревогу по поводу матерного коммента создал, а реакции ноль

Comment: @rjhdby а после выборов будет в 5/3 раза больше, чем ноль! Голосуй, а то проиграешь!

Comment: @alexolut зачем голосовать - я лучше выдвинусь.

Comment: Когда кандидаты дадут свои ответы, было бы интересно и от действующих модераторов послушать варианты.

Comment: @alexolut Это вопросы для только  для кандидатов!

Comment: Ишь... избрались, чтобы на вопросы не отвечать!

Answer (score 21):

Вы — модератор. Поздно ночью вы открываете ленту новых вопросов и видите:

> Что лучше учить, Java или C#?

Похоже, что автор вопроса — новичок как на сайте, так и в программировании. Ему нужно помочь освоиться.

Вы переходите в вопрос, чтобы оставить пару комментариев. Оказывается, там уже есть пара десятков комментариев.

Первый — от хорошо знакомого вам участника.
Вы часто общаетесь в чате, возможно вместе работаете или дружите за пределами сайта.
Он хороший специалист и весело шутит в чате.

Комментарий у него тоже шутливый, даже саркастический.
Похоже, что шутка понравилась всем, кроме новичка — комментарий заплюсован.
А новичок ответил довольно резко, получил такой же резкий ответ от вашего знакомого и ещё раз ответил — уже матом.
Ваш знакомый на мат не сорвался, но продолжает спор.
Новые комментарии появляются прямо сейчас.

Раньше вы уже видели подобные споры с участием вашего знакомого и нескольких других новичков.

Уже ночь, остальные модераторы спят, вам придётся действовать самостоятельно.

Вопросы:

1. Что вы будете делать с вопросом, с новичком и с вашим знакомым?
2. Почему вы приняли такое решение? На какой результат вы рассчитываете?
3. Если вы решили написать кому-либо из участников — дополните свой ответ текстом этого сообщения.

---

Персонаж «знакомый» — собирательный и в значительной степени выдуманный. Я не имел в виду кого-либо конкретного и прошу вас не приписывать мои фантазии конкретным людям. Если хотите хардкора — представьте на этом месте вашего лучшего друга.

Comment: Крайне интересный прикладной вопрос!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я задействовал все творческие резервы и пишу хардкорную ролевую игру с моральным выбором. На очереди второй вопрос. :)

Comment: Какой-то никакой вопрос: знакомого в чате (или другим каналам связи) попросить прекратить эскалацию конфликта, комменты (с вопросом о_0) потереть, а новичку объяснить (от себя или ссылкой на справку). Какие ещё варианты-то?

Comment: @Skyrocker усложненный вариант - то же самое повторяется несколько раз, с разными новичками, но одним и тем же старичком. Старичок на замечания в чате каждый раз отвечает "ок", но продолжает. Ваши действия? :)

Comment: Платон мне друг, но истина дороже. (c). Собсно @Skyrocker меня тут опередил. Плюсую.

Comment: @Skyrocker за мат в адрес участников вообще-то бан полагается.

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда извини, друг, сам виноват, так что это ни разу не усложнённый вариант. Интересно, то намёк на юзера Ипатьев или Squidward?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не знал. Без проблем - забаним новичка! Сожжём праведным огнём.

Comment: @Skyrocker оба раза не угадали. Это вообще не намек на кого-то конкретного. Проблема появилась, когда ещё не было сайта ru.so. И на прошлых выборах такой вопрос был, правда под другим соусом. Вот, например, [ответ от Squidward (Discord)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2147/2152#2152)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я понимаю что собирательно, ибо негоже так модератору делать! Ответы там, конечно, tl;dr.

Comment: @Skyrocker думаю, и в этот раз ответы можно будет издать небольшой книжкой. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, автобиография: как я стал (почти) модером SO или история моей жизни.

Comment: Ньюфагу в программировании не нужно помогать освоиться, поскольку это просто невозможно. Потому сносим вопрос со всеми комментариями.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov вы не обосновали свое мнение и я с ним не согласен, так что вопрос остается.

Comment: На самом деле тут выигрышная ситуация. С другом можно договориться за кадром и потом публично его осадить в вопросе, причём так, чтобы сообщество увидело вашу готовность жертвовать личным ради интересов сообщества. Это укрепило бы авторитет модераторов и веру в справедливость на SO.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если друг после этого действительно перестанет троллить новичков, то все останутся в выигрыше, mission accomplised.

Comment: @PashaPash усложнил вопрос по вашей подсказке.

Answer (score 19):

Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?

Я не имею в виду явный спам или вопросы, вовсе не относящиеся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее вопросы от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Answer (score 16):

Вы — модератор. Сегодня у вас хорошее настроение и вы обрабатываете очередь тревог.

Некий участник задал несколько неудачных вопросов подряд.
Один из них закрыт как провоцирующий холивары, ещё два — слишком общие, в остальных не хватает минимального примера кода.

Заметно, что позавчера система запретила ему задавать новые вопросы. 
Вчера он завел новую учётку и продолжает спрашивать с того же IP.

Как и всегда в таких случаях, вы отправляете ему шаблонное письмо с полезными ссылками и блокируете учётку на 1 день.

Через полчаса вы получаете ответное сообщение.
В нём участник оскорбляет вас, желает мучительной смерти вашим близким, угрожает связями с силовыми структурами, организованной преступностью и национальными диаспорами.

Он также заявляет, что сайт прогнил, а все участники сообщества — дилетанты и люди низшего сорта. Находиться среди таких людей — ниже его достоинства, поэтому он намерен покинуть сайт навсегда.

В конце сообщения участник требует прислать ему ваши ФИО, номер паспорта и место прописки, чтобы он мог направить в ваш адрес судебный иск за ущемление гражданских прав и свобод.

Вопрос: **что вы будете делать?**

---

Чисто технически, инструменты модератора позволяют вам:

- Ответить на сообщение;
- Перебанить на более долгий срок;
- Удалить или уничтожить (вместе с вопросами) учётку;
- Отметить его вопрос как спам, чтобы система забанила IP;
- Узнать личные данные и IP участника;
- Обратиться к менеджеру сообщества с любой просьбой (он может отказать).

Comment: этот вопрос абстрактный или попадались такие оригинальные личности?)

Comment: @pavel тут тоже собирательный образ. Всё вместе не попадалось, но каждая деталь основана на реальном случае.

Comment: Вы специально придумываете такие вопросы, чтобы отсеять желающих облечься властью?

Comment: @edem чтобы отсеять адекватные ожидания от завышенных. :)

Comment: @edem, всё проще: ["так говорят только действующие ромбовые бездельники, чтобы отпугнуть конкурентов :)"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=40359699#40359699).

Comment: @pavel регулярно сталкиваюсь с подобным. Причём количество готовых на угрозы и оскорбления за последние 15 лет моего модераторского опыта всё растёт и растёт.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev видимо, надеются «войти в айти», открывая дверь пинком.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev кстати, а где и что вы модерируете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin начал в 2002-м с популярного Иркутского чата. Потом несколько технических форумов. Сейчас я один из модераторов Тостера.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ого, вот это опыт. Может быть, поделитесь опытом на Мете или в подкасте у Nicolas'а поучаствуете?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А еще лучше, выдвигайте свою кандидатуру на пост модератора Stack Overflow на русском!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev поддерживаю предложение Николаса )

Answer (score 11):

В этом ответе вы можете найти набор базовых вопросов, призванных раскрыть как можно более общую информацию о кандидате. Как написано в инструкциях выше, первые два вопроса гарантированно появятся в итоговой сессии вопросов и ответов. Остальные — только в том случае, если сообщество опубликует недостаточно вопросов. Если вы считаете, что какой-то вопрос из списка, помимо двух верхних, должен войти в итоговую сессию, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в виде отдельного ответа.

- Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?
- Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

- Что, по вашему мнению, делает модератор?
- «Ромб» будет добавлен ко всему, что вы говорите и говорили в прошлом, включая вопросы, ответы и комментарии, а все, что вы сделаете в будущем, будет оценено под другим ракурсом. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?
- Каким образом статус модератора сделает ваши действия более эффективными в сравнении с ситуацией, когда вы просто наберете 10 или 20 тысяч баллов репутации?

Answer (score 7):

Готовы ли вы исправлять ошибки локализации в интерфейсе модератора и/или публиковать соответствующие баг-репорты на местной и/или главной Мете в зависимости от источника проблемы?

Comment: На мой взгляд, у сообщества нет такой потребности. Это полезно в целом, но далеко не самое полезное.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну, лучше, конечно узнать про табы и ОС, ога

Comment: то вообще шутки, они точно не пройдут.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а это будет полезно всем модераторам. Не стоит забывать еще и про rusSE, и все будущие поколения.

Comment: Поясню, чтобы не было недоразумений. Задача модератора — работать на благо сообщества. А перевод строк в инструментах модератора может быть только на благо самих модераторов. На сообщество это не повлияет. Поэтому это — не задача модератора.

Comment: И если уж совсем прямо: я вам благодарен за то, что вы много сил вкладываете в перевод. Но это, на мой взгляд, ортогонально способности быть модератором. При этом у вас есть другие качества и достижения, которые влияют на эту способность.

Comment: @NickVolynkin обо мне тут речи вообще не идёт. Мне просто было бы интересно услышать ответ кандидатов на поставленный вопрос. Всё-таки из-за того, что движок "не наш" и сотрудник только один, поправить эту гуйню можно только с помощью ромбовых участников. Если бы была возможность видеть интерфейс модератора хотя бы в режиме read-only, то вопрос бы не возник вовсе.

Comment: @alexolut интерфейса модератора, как такового нет. это пачка разных кнопочек, раскиданных по разным местам. imho, лучше модератор будет тратить свое время на модерацию, чем на улучшение перевода интерфейса для модераторов :)

Comment: @PashaPash пожалуйста, пусть тратит. Но если кто из кандидатов даст утвердительный ответ на мой вопрос, у него будет больше шансов получить мой голос.

Comment: @alexolut выдвигайтесь сами и исправляйте что угодно :) "Проверить блокировки" (review bans) ждет вас!

Comment: @PashaPash слишком много лишнего балласта в нагрузку идёт с таким предложением. Создать багрепорт не так долго и не требует такой регулярности как модерация.

Comment: @alexolut да неважно сколько времени это требует. Просто странно,  что количество людей,  которым важна локализации модераторских утилит превышает количество пользователей этих самых утилит. Аж 9 человек считают,  что это важный вопрос.  А касается он напрямую всего 6-х.

Comment: @PashaPash это говорит о том, насколько модераторы далеки от обычного участника и его желаний :-D

Comment: @PashaPash странно не то, что 9 проголосовало "за", а то, что 5 проголосовало "против". Такое ощущение, что это было воспринято не как вопрос для кандидата для проверки его отношения к проблемам перевода сайта, а как обязательное требование для избрания в модераторы - собственноручно исправлять подобные ошибки. То есть пока я эти 5 минусов воспринимаю как "английский интерфейс хорош, давайте его оставим, русский язык не нужен".

Comment: @alexolut Я один из тех, кто поставил минус. потому что считаю, что отношение модератора к качеству локализации утилит, видимых только модератору, никак не влияет на его качества как модератора. Если вам хочется улучшить качество перевода этих утилит - дерните любого из действующих модераторов, он вам наскриншотит. И я поставил минус не потому, что мне "русский язык не нужен (вообще на всем сайте)". А потому, что это *не имеет никакого отношения* к выборам.

Comment: @alexolut т.е. с моей точки зрения, если модератор между "попереводить видимую только ему админку" и "поразгребать тревоги, которых уже под сотню" выбирает "попереводить" - значит он так себе модератор. Т.к. для сообщества лучше выбрать того, кто выберет "поразребать". Потому что он будет решать проблемы сообщества. А не свои собственные :)

Comment: @alexolut я более чем уверен, что из 9 поставивших плюс все 9 прочитали текст наискосок. примерно так: "настройки локализации доступны только модератороам. готовы ли модераторы локализовать сайт?". т.е. обобщили точно так же, как и вы - "участника не напрягает чуть кривой русский перевод **утилит модератороа**" -> "участник за английский интерфейс и не хочет русский интерфейс **всего сайта**". "модераторы далеки от обычного участника и его желаний!" - у 9 *обычных* участников есть страстное желание подправить перевод кнопок, видимых только другим 4-м участникам :)

Comment: @alexolut модераторы как раз заботятся о потребностях обычных участников. А участник, который страстно желает перевода элементов интерфейса, которые он даже никогда не видит — это очень необычный участник.

Comment: @PashaPash Вы так говорите про разгребание очередей, как будто кроме этого модератор больше ничего и не может сделать полезного в отведенное ему время. Решительного единоличного голоса модераторы вообще судя по всему боятся (об этом как раз писал Nofate), а то бы уже давно очередь на закрытие обнулили. Если готовы понакидать репортов, то покидайте, будет хорошо, если удасться что-то там улучшить и без ромба на хвосте.

Comment: @NickVolynkin значит, у нас сообщество необычных людей. Это ли не хорошо?!

Comment: @PashaPash ну и не забывайте всё же, что сообщество у нас на русском. А если интерфейс модератора английский, это автоматически требует от модератора знаний соответствующего языка, то есть ограничивает круг кандидатов. Давайте тогда добавим обязательное требование к кандидату на должность модератора, чтобы всё было честно.

Comment: @alexolut интерфейс модератора русский, с небольшими багами в переводе. Баги не настолько серьезные, чтобы ради них тратить время на багрепорт, т.к. они совсем не мешают основной работе. Поэтому странно, что наличие каких-то потенциальных багов так важно для этих 9-ти участников. Модераторы не боятся единоличного голоса, но разгребсти очередь на закртытие в 200+ тревог, уделяя время каждому вопросу, и проявляя знание во всех технических областях, они не могут. И не должны - очеред на закрытие гораздо эффективнее разгребают обычные участники. Точнее, разгребали. Сейчас почему-то перестали.

Comment: Я тут вспомнил, что в первые пару недель после получения ромба я прошерстил интерфейс своих новых инструментов и много строк поправил. Но потом, во-первых, привык, что иногда встречаются непереведенные строки; а во-вторых обычно были более приоритетные задачи.

Answer (score 6):

> - При наличии ромба **ваши голоса** на закрытие вопросов и в проверках, а также тревоги на комментариях **будут решающими**. Вы перестанете быть частью электората, вы станете единоличным судьёй и палачом, с возможностью выносить единогласные (свои) решения по вопросам, которые в обычных ситуациях требуют голосов 3-5 человек.
>
> <sup>Источник: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6022/208074</sup>

Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли перефразировать вопрос так, чтобы ответ был развернутым? Сейчас, как мне кажется, большенство кандидатов просто ответят «Да».

Comment: Можно спросить «что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись».

Comment: @NickVolynkin, учитывая серьёзную недоработанность ответа, сделал его общим.

Comment: @Arhad думаю, это было необязательно. )

Answer (score 4):

Среди вопросов кандидатам я вижу вариации на тему *«Расскажите, что у нас на сайте плохо и как могло бы быть лучше, будь на то ваша воля»*.

Я уверен, что этот вопрос бесполезен: прямой ответ на него не релевантен способности модерировать сайт и вообще слабо связан с реальностью.

Для изменений недостаточно воли в том смысле, в котором она используется в выражении «будь на то ваша воля». Для изменений нужно волевое действие, которое конкретный человек выполняет:

- осмысленно,
- целенаправленно
- и продолжительно.

Такое волевое дейстие приносит результаты и отлично характеризует личность деятеля.

*Например, один знакомый мне участник написал отличную статью справки об этике и уважении к новичкам. Другой перебрал тысячи мигрированных вопросов и ответов и навёл в них порядок. Многие фактически «усыновили» какую-нибудь метку и заботятся о каждом вопросе: приветствуют новичков, редактируют, отвечают, находят ссылки на связанные проблемы.*

Поэтому, вопрос:

**Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали, каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.**

Если вы уже пашете на благо сайта — я вижу причины приделать вам реактивный двигатель.

Но, пожалуйста, не пишите рассказов в жанре «Кабы я была царица». То, что вы могли бы сделать, но пока что не сделали, вас никак не характеризует.

Answer (score 3):

В чём Вы видите главные проблемы Stack Overflow на русском?

Что бы Вы изменили в Stack Overflow на русском, будь на то Ваша воля?

Answer (score 3):

Положим, участник Stack Overflow на русском в дискуссиях с оппонентами в сообщениях и комментариях регулярно использует следующий набор слов с негативной коннотацией: `бред`, `убрал мусор`, `деструктивно`, `простыня текста` и т. п., из-за чего оппонентам некомфортно общаться с ним. И вот, Вы увидели тревоги к сообщениям этого участника. Как Вы поступите, если

- участник новичок или почти новичок, имеет сравнительно низкую репутацию;
- участник имеет большой положительный вклад.

?

Comment: Слишком много вопросов от тебя. Сложно голосовать, потому что система будет откатывать множественные голоса за вопросы одного участника (больше 3-4).

Comment: А что деструктивного в слове «деструктивно»? Я его однажды [использовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134183/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-pull-request/598162#comment875793_598162) в отношении вашего ответа и я могу обосновать свою точку зрения. Если вы считаете, что это не соответствует be-nice, то, пожалуйста, объясните причину.

Comment: @Qwertiy только этот «вопрос» на самом деле ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на Ваш взгляд, должен обладать хороший модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: Почему именно четыре?

Comment: @alexolut, возможно, чтобы совсем уж главные качества были? Ну, чтобы кандидат тщательнее обдумал свои приоритеты. Хотя, да, три было бы более нумерологично.

Answer (score 2):

Положим, Вы увидели тревогу на комментарий следующего содержания:

> Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что забыто волшебное слово "бегом!"

Ваши действия, если участник позволяет себе подобные комментарии:

- однократно,
- многократно.

?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в марте 2017-го ещё не существовало стандартизированный причины «Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи...» Ну а так как [список причин, унаследованный с Хэшкода](https://gist.github.com/NickVolynkin/bc62b4d4615635e597ae) не был даже предложен в качестве рекомендации, то каждый комментировал кто во что горазд. Однако сейчас ситуация стабилизировалась.

Answer (score 2):

Какое на Ваш взгляд в сообществе отношение к новичкам? Всё ли отлично и замечательно?

Если нет, что бы Вы предложили поменять?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6026/178988

Comment: Как мне кажется, это не лучший вопрос модераторам, так как вы спрашиваете просто мнение. Мнение может быть абсолютно любое, при это человек все равно может быть хорошим модератором.

Answer (score 1):

В должности модератора Вам предстоит блокировать участников. Чем Вы будете руководствоваться, выбирая сроки блокировок?

Считаете ли Вы, что в правилах проекта (как, вероятно, в законодательстве любого государства) должны присутствовать пункты о сроках наказания за нарушения вида «такое-то нарушение — такое-то наказание с таким-то сроком»?

Comment: Не уверен, но вроде срок блокировки выбирает система изходя из предыдущих блокировок участника.

Comment: @alexolut нет, выбирают модераторы, руководствуясь своими правилами, коллективным обсуждением и здравым смыслом. Есть стандартные сроки, которые применяются чаще всего: 7 дней в первый раз, 30 во второй, 365 в третий и далее.

Comment: @NickVolynkin попытался связать эти два предложения и не смог.

Comment: @alexolut есть стандартные сроки, но модератор всегда принимает окончательное решение и руками выбирает нужный срок. Можно на 666 дней заблокировать, можно на день. Можно даже обратно разблокировать, но я зарекся так делать — тогда нет воспитательного эффекта.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, новые модераторы смогут также модерировать чат.

Положим, Вы увидели тревоги на следующие сообщения, оставленные в чате, не сообщениях или комментариях:

- > А товарищ по ссылке выше: что-то паталогически-маниакально зациклен на себе и своей возлюбленной и личности..;
- > Астрологи объявили неделю нытья. Количество нытья увеличилось вдвое :-).

Ваши действия?

Comment: А почему нормальные ссылки нельзя было дать?

Comment: @alexolut, очевидно нельзя, чтобы не было возможности уничтожить свидетельства.

Comment: @Arhad пфф... да кому это надо!?

Comment: Примечательно, что вы сохранили обе страницы ещё 10 марта.

Comment: Хм.. Простой ответ: для чата эти фразы нормальны. Особенно вторая, т. к. в ней даже нет упоминания конкретных ситуаций. "Неделя нытья и мне тоже хочется поныть" - ok, почему бы нет? С первой, возможно, надо быть осторожней, но сама по себе она приемлема.

Comment: Астрологи вообще [много чего объявляют](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%90%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8&user=&room=22462) )

Answer (score 1):

На Мете участниками — не «старожилами» не раз поднималась тема «неаргументированных минусов», т. е. функционала, позволяющего ставить минусы сообщениям участников без каких-либо комментариев.

Всё ли Вас устраивает в существующем положении вещей по данному вопросу?

Comment: Модератор в любом случае не имеет права идти против большинства голосов, иначе быстро лишится должности.

Comment: Не устраивает, но модераторы ничего не могут с этим поделать. Этот вопрос регулярно поднимается на metaSE и metaSO и стабильно отклоняется. Вот свежий вопрос на эту тему со сводкой других: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/4928642

Answer (score -1):

Какие Вам известны блокировки НЕ вандалов/спамеров с нулевым положительным вкладом в Stack Overflow на русском?

Всё ли оптимально по Вашему мнению в этих блокировках?

Comment: Факт блокировки — это модераторская тайна, то есть такие случаи надо отслеживать самому. Но, во-первых, отслеживать судьбу [почти ста тысяч пользователей](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/150894/stackoverflow-total-users-count) невозможно в принципе. Во-вторых, надо иметь >10k репутации для доступа к затёртым сообщениям (если не успел увидеть всё сам).

Comment: @Arhad искать заблокированных можно через SEDE, кстати.

Comment: @alexolut, а какое поле хранит подобную информацию? *Оффтоп: кстати, у них полный атас с нормализацией*.

Comment: @Arhad там хитрее приходится действовать: надо искать участника с единичной репутацией, но несколькими знаками.

Comment: Есть и  другие категории участников с нулевым положительным вкладом, кроме спамеров и вандалов.

Comment: Вы про случаи с блокировками "чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться"? Не очень понимаю, что в них можно обсуждать. Они обычно выдаются на стандартные сроки. Разве что обсудить эти сроки и их (почти-экспоненциальную) градацию.