# Как добавить картинку в комментарий?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, форматирование

Я хочу проиллюстрировать свой комментарий. Как загрузить картинку на imgur, чтобы она появилась в комментарии?

Comment: Вопрос и ответ написал по следам обсуждения в вопросе [Куб минимального объема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727267/181472)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В комментарии [нельзя добавлять изображения и другое сложное форматирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Но вы можете разместить ссылку на картинку. Загрузите её через редактирование вопроса, а полученную ссылку добавьте в комментарий.

## Пошаговая инструкция:

### 1. Откройте редактирование нового вопроса

Нужная кнопка всегда находится в верхнем левом углу:

[image: задать вопрос]

### 2. Загрузите и вставьте картинку

Нажмите <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> или кнопку в редакторе:

> [image: кнопка добавления картинки]

### 3. Из полученного текста заберите ссылку

> [image: ссылка находится в конце текста]

Теперь редактирование можно отменить.

### 4. Опубликуйте эту ссылку в комментарии.

> [image: ссылка добавлена в комментарий]

Comment: хм, а просто на imgur нельзя сходить?

Comment: @Андрей нет. Делайте так как сказал настоящий модератор!

Comment: @Андрей да конечно можно. Это просто один из удобных способов.

Comment: А что за `auto` рядом со ссылкой «справка» на последней картинке?

Comment: @alexolut, тссс, утечка

Comment: @Андрей скорее всего баг, который [не считается достаточно полезным](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5983/%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-2017/5989#comment22923_5989) для исправления и документирования.

Comment: @alexolut это https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se, сторонний продукт, который нельзя локализовать через Tx.

Comment: @alexolut, т.е баг который фича: https://geektimes.ru/post/293737/

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну ладно. Живите пока :)

Comment: @Андрей, нет. Обрати внимание на адрес загруженной картинки: `i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png` - stack - у SO есть какое-то соглашение с imgur'ом, а если сходить на сайт, то правила будут другие. А вот вместо нового вопроса вполне подходит поле нового ответа - всегда им пользуюсь.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, да. Что-то не обратил внимание, что Ник пишет про новый **вопрос**. Я всегда делаю именно через **ответ**, так не нужно покидать текущую вкладку.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, проще через ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin может подправить тогда текст?